# "Geht's" becomes "gehts"

Tags: spelling, apostrophe

This is a title from the book "German Grammar in a Nutshell" by  Langenscheidt

[image]

I suppose the word *gehts* stands for *geht's* (which is a clitic form of *geht es*).
Is it correct to drop out the apostrophe? Is it correct to use the full form *geht es* in the above sentence?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Duden says in [„Regel 14 Absatz 4“](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph):

> Bei umgangssprachlichen Verbindungen eines Verbs oder einer
>   Konjunktion mit dem Pronomen „es" ist der Apostroph entbehrlich; er
>   wird jedoch häufig verwendet.
>
> - Wie gehts (*auch*: geht's) dir?
> - Nimms (*auch*: Nimm's) nicht so schwer.
> - Wenns (*auch*: Wenn's) weiter nichts ist …

So it's obviously alright to drop out the apostrophe.

**Edit:**

The official orthography rules ([link to the *Institut für deutsche Sprache*](http://www.ids-mannheim.de/service/reform/)) state that there are three cases where you *have* to use the apostrophe. It also mentions when you're allowed to use it:

> **§ 96 Man setzt den Apostroph in drei Gruppen von Fällen.**
>
> Dies betrifft
>
> (1) Eigennamen, deren Grundform (Nominativform) auf einen s-Laut
>   (geschrieben: `-s`, `-ss`, `-ß`, `-tz`, `-z`, `-x`, `-ce`) endet, bekommen im
>   Genitiv den Apostroph, wenn sie nicht einen Artikel, ein
>   Possessivpronomen oder dergleichen bei sich haben:
>
> *Aristoteles’
>   Schriften, Carlos’ Schwester, Ines’ gute Ideen, Felix’ Vorschlag,
>   Heinz’ Geburtstag, Alice’ neue Wohnung*
>
> E1: Aber ohne Apostroph: *die
>   Schriften des Aristoteles, die Schwester des Carlos, der Geburtstag
>   unseres kleinen Heinz*
>
> E2: Der Apostroph steht auch, wenn `-s`, `-z`, `-x`
>   usw. in der Grundform stumm sind: *Cannes’ Filmfestspiele, Boulez’
>   bedeutender Beitrag, Giraudoux’ Werke*
>
> (2) Wörter mit Auslassungen, die
>   ohne Kennzeichnung schwer lesbar oder missverständlich sind:
>
> *In
>   wen’gen Augenblicken ... ’s ist schade um ihn. Das Wasser rauscht’,
>   das Wasser schwoll.*
>
> (3) Wörter mit Auslassungen im Wortinneren wie:
>
> *D’dorf (= Düsseldorf), M’gladbach (= Mönchengladbach), Ku’damm (=
>   Kurfürstendamm)*
>
> **§ 97**
>
> Man kann den Apostroph setzen, wenn Wörter gesprochener Sprache
>   mit Auslassungen bei schriftlicher Wiedergabe undurchsichtig sind.
>
> *der
>   Käpt’n, mit’m Fahrrad Bitte, nehmen S’ (= Sie) doch Platz! Das war
>   ’n (= ein) Bombenerfolg!*
>
> E: Von dem Apostroph als Auslassungszeichen
>   zu unterscheiden ist der gelegentliche Gebrauch dieses Zeichens zur
>   Verdeutlichung der Grundform eines Personennamens vor der
>   Genitivendung `-s` oder vor dem Adjektivsuffix `-sch`: *Carlo’s Taverne,
>   Einstein’sche Relativitätstheorie*

This not only confirms that you're allowed to drop it but suggests (at least to me) that  *default* version is without.

Comment: As stated in the quote, this form is colloquial, so I think it's not appropriate for a (formal) book.

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct to use the full form *geht es*, yes, most certainly.

Is it correct to drop out the apostrophe? I honestly don't know. Does it rub me the wrong way? The answer is no, so in my book it is okay :)